# Doing black magic to make a person fall in love with someone

Tags: allah, shirk, tawba, sihr

What should I do after enternaining the thought of doing magic to make a man fall in love with me? What if I did some magic? Should I give up all forms of beautification for my repentance to be complete?

Answer (score 1):

Sihr (black magic) is haram in Islam, is a huge sin, and a form of disbelief. The biggest use of Sihr is for breaking up marriages, so what would give you the idea that Sihr would make someone fall in love with you?

[Quran 2:102](https://quran.com/2?startingVerse=102)

> They ˹instead˺ followed the magic promoted by the devils during the reign of Solomon. Never did Solomon disbelieve, rather the devils disbelieved. They taught magic to the people, along with what had been revealed to the two angels, Hârût and Mârût, in Babylon. The two angels never taught anyone without saying, “We are only a test ˹for you˺, so do not abandon ˹your˺ faith.” Yet people learned ˹magic˺ that caused a rift ˹even˺ between husband and wife; although their magic could not harm anyone except by Allah’s Will. They learned what harmed them and did not benefit them—although they already knew that whoever buys into magic would have no share in the Hereafter. Miserable indeed was the price for which they sold their souls, if only they knew!

If you've committed Sihr, repent sincerely to Allah and don't get close to Sihr ever again.

[Sihr and Its Types](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/9432/sihr-and-its-types)

Comment: Jammooly I amMuslim and  am I still Muslim after that and  I have a question if someone do black magic at age of 17 to make someone fall in love with you and that person is not married and other magic trick just for fun not to harm someone so what are the consequences of black magic on that person and hereafter what is the punishment and do a person still have a chance to repent how to ask forgiveness and what about the consequences? Will I still face punishment even if I repent.

Comment: If you want to know if there's anything specific you should do in repenting such as paying Kaffarah, I suggest you speak to a scholar of Islam about this. Allah's mercy is vast, repent sincerely, consult a scholar about repentance , then don't get close to Sihr ever again.

A plain magic trick and black magic are different. I hope you're not getting those two confused.

Avoid sinning and avoid sins that'll take you out of Islam. May we all die as believers, Ameen.

Comment: Jammooly JazakAllah khair for your help